# Recorrer objeto de objetos

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de recorrer un objeto de objetos, pero no se como mostrar los valores del objeto interno.

```
const data = {
numeros: {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [3, 4],
    2: [5, 6],
    3: [7, 8],
    4: [9, 10],
},
vocales: {
    0: ['a'],
    1: ['e'],
    2: ['i'],
    3: ['o'],
    4: ['u'],
    
}}
```

Por ahora solo tengo esto,

```
for (let elemento of Object.keys(data)){
    console.log(data[elemento]);
}
```

Pero quiero mostrar por ejemplo solo las vocales así

```
// a,e,i,o,u
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la estructura de tu objeto, pues dentro de tu objeto tienes 2 objetos más, y dentro de las propiedades de estos objetos tienes arreglos.
Lo que hice fue mapear las keys del objeto que se encuentra en la propiedad vocales de tu objeto data, y ya con esto, corro un arreglo que recorra todos los valores que se encuentran dentro de este segundo arreglo, y lo que tengan dentro lo pusheo en un arreglo nuevo que llamo arrVocales

```js
const data = {
numeros: {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [3, 4],
    2: [5, 6],
    3: [7, 8],
    4: [9, 10],
},
vocales: {
    0: ['a'],
    1: ['e'],
    2: ['i'],
    3: ['o'],
    4: ['u'],
    
}}

const arrVocales = []

Object.keys(data.vocales).forEach(element => {
  data.vocales[element].forEach(vocal => {
    arrVocales.push(vocal)
  })
})

console.log(arrVocales)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que ingresar a **`vocales`** para recorrer sus valores, lo puedes hacer con [**`Object.keys()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Ahora para tener este resultado, tendrías que usar el método [**`toString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) para que el arreglo **`result`** te lo devuelva como una cadena tipo **`string`**:

```
// a,e,i,o,u
```

Tu código sería el siguiente:

```js
const data = {
  numeros: {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [3, 4],
    2: [5, 6],
    3: [7, 8],
    4: [9, 10],
  },
  vocales: {
    0: ['a'],
    1: ['e'],
    2: ['i'],
    3: ['o'],
    4: ['u'],
  },
};

const result = [];

// recorremos las claves de "vocales".
Object.keys(data.vocales).forEach(element => {
  // de las claves, recorremos sus valores.
  data.vocales[element].forEach(vocales => {
    // los valores obtenidos lo pusheamos a "result"
    result.push(vocales);
  });
});

// imprimimos a "result" como una cadena string.
console.log(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma, respetando un poco lo que ya tenias, sería usando los valores (mediante el método [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) y llamando al objeto interno directamente por su clave (**data.vocales**).

Luego, sabiendo la estructura interna del objeto *data.vocales*, que está compuesto de arrays con un solo elemento, por ejemplo, **['a']**, podemos sacarlo apuntando a su número de índice dentro del array, el cual, al ser único, va a ser **0**.

Y una vez encontrado lo agregamos a un nueva nueva variable de array de **salida**, que he denominado `array_vocales`, la cual ya hemos inicializado antes del bucle, y le vamos agregando los elementos mediante el método [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Y finalmente, una vez ya fuera del bucle, podemos volcar todo el array en modo texto separado por comas gracias al método [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Todo esto junto se resume en código así:

```js
const data = {
numeros: {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [3, 4],
    2: [5, 6],
    3: [7, 8],
    4: [9, 10],
},
vocales: {
    0: ['a'],
    1: ['e'],
    2: ['i'],
    3: ['o'],
    4: ['u'],
    
}}
let array_vocales = []
for (let elemento of Object.values(data.vocales)){
    array_vocales.push(elemento[0]);
}
console.log(array_vocales.join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar:

`Object.values`: Para obtener solo los array con las letras

`flat`: Para convertir todos esos array de una letra, en un solo array con las 5 letras

`join`: Para unirlo todas las letras en un solo string separado por coma

```js
const data = {
  numeros: {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [3, 4],
    2: [5, 6],
    3: [7, 8],
    4: [9, 10]
  },
  vocales: {
    0: ['a'],
    1: ['e'],
    2: ['i'],
    3: ['o'],
    4: ['u']
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(data.vocales).flat().join(","))
```